# Fast hash for 32 bit number into an array

Tags: c++, hash

I'm looking for a fast associative array that will allow me to map a 32 bit number to some element in an array, preferably a unique one so there aren't any clashes.  There are only a few thousand or so of these numbers but they can be anywhere in the 32 bit range.

I could use a *std::map* or *std::unordered_map* of course, but I was hoping there's a perfect hash solution to this problem that would speed things up a lot.  With only a few thousand it's also possible just std::find on the array and storing *std::pair* of key-value would be efficient too.

For reference what I want to do is map message Ids to a table of function pointers.

Comment: Are the message IDs sequential, by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I can add that I don't mind the "setup" time involved here, as once the associations are configured there are no additions or removals.

Comment: There **is** such a thing as perfect hashing, and it's appropriate for this situation, but it is not a runtime thing. You need an offline algorithm to deduce the perfect hash function from the possible inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you reread your question, it might answer itself.  You've basically asked, given a completely random set of 32 bit integers, how to turn them into 32 bit integers. If they are truly random, and you cannot tolerate any clashes, then there is only one answer: hash(x) = x.

Of course, that answer doesn't do you any good. The other option is to exploit knowledge about the nature of the message ids. Are they nearly sequential? Hash(x) = x - someConstant.  Can you throw away some bits?  Hash(x) = (x & ~0xff) >> 8. Maybe that will give you some ideas.

Comment: You're right, they're not perfectly random (from my reading I vaguely understand entropy is something to do with the solution).  They're mostly < 5000 with a few special cases that may be anywhere in the range.

Comment: Your special case hash function could return x if x <5000 and do special processing for higher numbers.  That would be lightning fast for all except the special cases if you can afford the memory for a 5k element array (assuming the large array doesn't start to cause cache misses).